# Access and modify a variable from inner anonymous class

Tags: java, android, realm

I have the following code:

```
boolean gameSuccess = false;
@Override
    public boolean saveMission(final Mission mission) {
        realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);

        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.copyToRealm(mission);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: mission saved");
                realm.close();
                missionSuccess = true;
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: mission failed");
                realm.close();
                missionSuccess = false;
            }
        });
        return gameSuccess;
    }
```

gameSuccess is always false even if onSuccess was called. What is the way to get this done?

Comment: Are you sure OnSucces is performed before you return gameSuccess?

Comment: it is async. so it happens before return or in another thread. I am asking how to wait and return the value when all callbacks have been done?

Answer (score 0):

Async isn't blocking, so your code is wrong. The transaction doesn't happen before the return, but any unspecified time later, which is why it is always false.

You either need to provide a callback to your method or convert the transaction to blocking

```
public void saveMission(final Mission mission, Callback callback) {
     realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.copyToRealm(mission);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: mission saved");
                realm.close(); 
                callback.onSuccess();
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: mission failed");
                realm.close();
                callback.onError();
            }
        });
}
```

or

```
realm.executeTransaction(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason for this variable is just to test. How to test this method if it onSuccess was called without ruining the original method with a testing callback?